# jQuery $.each() bug

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below is meant to compare two arrays and then return the difference, however it only seems to work when the last value of the array gets removed, can someone help ? 
When it works : 
array1 : [lol,lol2]
array2 : [lol,lol2,lol3]
It will return lol3
When it doesnt work : 
array1 : [lol,lol3]
array2 : [lol,lol2,lol3]
It returns undefined

```
function getChange(array1,array2){
            $.each( array2,function(key,value){
                if(($.inArray(value,array1))!==-1){
                    found="notfound";
                }
                else
                {
                    no=false;
                    newVAL = value;
                    array1 = array2;
                    return false;
                }
            });
            if(no==false)
            {
                return newVAL;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please include example input that works and example input that fails. Also, I not really sure what you mean by "return the difference". Could you provide what the desired output is for some sample input?

Comment: I have in the post .

Comment: Your code is really confusing. What do you do with the `found` variable? What is `no`? What is `b`?

Comment: Sounds like you're having an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You set `found` to `"notfound"` but then you never use that anywhere. Further, you seem to be setting `found` to `"notfound"` only if the item in question was, in fact, found.

Comment: Well the issue I had was that I wanted to get the difference between two arrays , I looked over some stuff and all the code snippets i used didnt work so I tried creating my own.

Comment: It only works if the last value of the array is missing, otherwise it just returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

Getting the difference between two arrays can be done by just looping over each one and checking if each item exists in the other one. If it does, push it to a new array.

Also you don't need to use `$.each` for this -- just use native [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), or [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loops if you need to support older browsers.

There are also [libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=array%20difference) out there that will do this for you.

```
var fruits = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'orange'];
var fruits2 = ['apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'kiwi'];

console.log(getArrayDifference(fruits, fruits2));
// ['blueberry', 'banana', 'kiwi']

function getArrayDifference(arr1, arr2)
{   
    var difference = [];

    arr1.forEach(function(item) {
        if (!~arr2.indexOf(item)) {
            difference.push(item);
        }
    });

    arr2.forEach(function(item) {
        if (!~arr1.indexOf(item)) {
            difference.push(item);
        }
    });

    return difference;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uuy6bohe/2/)